# Default argument value method location

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm writing a macro and I'm trying to locate where the method that generates default values is located for a local case class.

For example, in a top level case class, like:

```
package foo

case class Goo(a: String = "wibble")
```

I can easily find the method that returns "wibble" as `<init>$default$N` defined on the companion object for `Goo`. So something like:

```
val defswithsymbols = universe.asInstanceOf[Definitions with SymbolTable with StdNames]
val defaultGetter = defswithsymbols.nme.defaultGetterName(defswithsymbols.nme.CONSTRUCTOR, index + 1)
val method = tpe.companion.member(TermName(defaultGetter.toString))
```

And then I can invoke method on `tpe.companion` to give me the default value.

However, if I have a case class defined inside a method, there is no companion object for the class (that I can find) and so I cannot locate the default argument generation method. But it must be defined somewhere right :)

Edit: I think this question can probably boil down to - where is the companion object located for case classes declared inside a method?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a case class, the compiler creates class files for the the main class and its companion object. It does the same for case classes defined inside the method. The only difference is that the class files are created with a filename that makes it inaccessible. It is somewhat similar to anonymous class filename.

For example:

```
class TestClass {
  new Runnable(){
     def run() = {
        //some Code
     }
  }
}
```

After compiling the above code, the compiler might generate the class file with name **TestClass$anon$1**. If you know this name, you can create instance of this anonymous inner class using reflection.

Refer the below sample code with case class defined inside a method.

```
class TestClass {
  def someMethod = {
    case class ClassInsideMethod()
  }
}

object Main extends App{
  val enclosingClass = classOf[TestClass]
  val enclosingInstance = Class.forName(enclosingClass.getName).newInstance().asInstanceOf[TestClass]
  private val classInsideMethodConstructor = Class.forName(enclosingClass.getName + "$ClassInsideMethod$2").getDeclaredConstructor(enclosingClass)
  classInsideMethodConstructor.newInstance(enclosingInstance)
}
```

I found that after compiling the code, the compiler did create class files for case class with the name **TestClass$ClassInsideMethod$2** and **TestClass$ClassInsideMethod$3$**. The class files are appended with a number. This naming would differ based on your compiler. In my case, using reflection I was able to create the instance of the case class defined inside the method.

TLDR; The compiler does create the companion object for the case class.

I hope this would answer your question.

Comment: This is after compilation has finished though. I need to access the companion object during compilation via the macro as I do for any non-nested case class.

Comment: You cant because you dont know the name of the class file for class nested inside method. Its naming is similar to anonymous classes which is inaccessible in our scope.

Comment: I don't need to know the location of the class file via reflection. Just need access to the type symbol for the companion (or wherever) the default and apply methods are located for this case class at macro time.

Comment: You cannot access it